# Perform Select at odd positions in the string

Tags: c#

I have to Replace the characters of input string at odd positions by next character in alphabet.
For Example

**Input**-   `ABCD`

**output**-  `BBDD`

I wanted something like this

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
char[] k = input.ToCharArray().Select((val,i) =>(i%2==0) && (char)((int)val +     1)).ToArray();
string output=new string(k)
```

Comment: what if input is `"zBZD"`?

Comment: Did you try to run and debug your code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, need to do little more to achieve the target. You have to notice the Following things and make those changes:

- The condition `i%2==0` determines whether the character needs to be replaced or not, so you have to apply the conditional operator(`?:`) here.
- For valid condition, you have to get the next character. For that you can try `(char)((int)x + 1)`. this will first evaluate `(int)x` and gives the integer value of that particular character. then add `1` to it then get the corresponding character.
- For false condition use the same character.
- After these steps you will get a character array, you can use `String.Join` to make the output string from the character array

You can try something like this:

```
string input = "ABCD";
char[] k = input.Select((x, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? (char)((int)x + 1) : x).ToArray();
string output = String.Join("",k);
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yXNxth)

Note the following things as well:

- In this code we have not restricted characters, if your input contains `Z` the next value from the ASCII table will be assigned, that will be `[`.
- If you want `z` to `a` and `Z` to `A` then you have to apply conditions for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
string output = string.Concat(input.Select((c, i) => (char)(c + ++i % 2)));
```

Comment: Some explanation might help.